# Meteor app is crashing

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, meteor, amazon-s3, meteor-slingshot

I am very new to meteor and am trying to start a previous employees app. I downloaded the repo and installed meteor. When I installed the npm packages and did `meteor run`, the app crashed.

It gives me this error.

```
Your app is crashing. Here's the latest log:
{ [Error: Cannot find module './build/Release/DTraceProviderBindings'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
{ [Error: Cannot find module './build/default/DTraceProviderBindings'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
{ [Error: Cannot find module './build/Debug/DTraceProviderBindings'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }

/Users/joey.diperi/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.3.2_4.yyk0ym.tlxjp++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:267
                        throw(ex);
                              ^
Error: Match error: Missing key 'AWSAccessKeyId'
    at exports.check (packages/check/match.js:34:1)
    at new Slingshot.Directive (packages/edgee_slingshot/packages/edgee_slingshot.js:304:1)
    at Object.Slingshot.createDirective (packages/edgee_slingshot/packages/edgee_slingshot.js:274:1)
    at meteorInstall.server.config.slingshot.js (server/config/slingshot.js:1:11)
    at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:141:1)
    at require (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:75:1)
    at /Users/joey.diperi/Documents/websites/bold_ideas/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/app/app.js:2723:1
    at /Users/joey.diperi/Documents/websites/bold_ideas/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:283:10
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/joey.diperi/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.3.2_4.yyk0ym.tlxjp++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
Exited with code: 8
Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

I see in the startup.js page there are properties attached to the `Meteor.settings` object. Are the deployment keys usually kept in the Meteor.settings object in meteor?

Comment: Something to read on settings and private keys here: https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/making-use-of-settings-json

Comment: Look if there's a `settings.json` file in the app and if so start the app with `meteor --settings settings.json`